# need help on output the console application

Tags: vb.net

below is a console application project for my college, which is working perfect except the output is disjointed, I'd like to have them like a table displayed...i don't know how to make the output like a table...

Module Module1

```
Dim college(4, 2)
Dim name As String
Dim Subject As String
Dim score As Decimal
Dim Record As Decimal
Dim Row As Decimal
Dim SortOut As Decimal
Dim TotRow As Decimal

Sub Main()

    Console.Write("Enter total number of student to process: ")
    Record = Console.ReadLine()

    SortOut = Record
    TotRow = Record - 1

    Row = TotRow

    Do While Row >= 0

        Console.Write("Enter Your Name: ")
        name = Console.ReadLine()


        Console.Write("Enter your subject : ")
        Subject = Console.ReadLine()


        Console.Write("Enter your score: ")
        score = Console.ReadLine()


        Call Input()

        Call RowStep()

    Loop


    Call Output()

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub

Sub Input()

    college(Row, 0) = name
    college(Row, 1) = Subject
    college(Row, 2) = score

End Sub

Sub RowStep()

    Row = Row - 1

End Sub


Sub Output()

    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine()

    Row = 0

    Do While Row < SortOut

        Console.WriteLine((college(Row, 0)))
        Console.WriteLine((college(Row, 1)))
        Console.WriteLine((college(Row, 2)))

        Row = Row + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: Please add a section showing what you mean by output like a table. It will help us help you. Probably also best to include the "disjoint" output you are getting now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "output like a table" you mean aligned in columns, then you can [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) all of your output.

```
Dim format as String = "{0,-25}{1,25}"

Console.WriteLine(String.Format(format, "Your name:", college(Row, 0)))
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(format, "Your subject:", college(Row, 1)))
Console.Writeline(String.Format(format, "Your score:", college(Row, 2)))
```

Which should output something that looks like:

```
Your name:    Justin Ryan
Your subject:   Chemistry
Your score:            42
```

There is also an overload of [Console.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aakt1eab(v=vs.110).aspx) which provides this same functionality.

```
Console.WriteLine(format, "Your name:", college(Row, 0))
Console.WriteLine(format, "Your subject:", college(Row, 1))
Console.Writeline(format, "Your score:", college(Row, 2))
```

---

Addition in response to asker's comment:

```
Dim format As String = "{0,-25}{1,-25}{2}"

Console.WriteLine(format, "Name:","Subject:","Score:")
Do While Row < SortOut
    Console.WriteLine(format, college(Row, 0), college(Row, 1), college(Row, 2))
    Row = Row + 1
Loop
```

Comment: I would like to have them like this:
Name                Subject           Score
Justin Ryan         Chemistry          42

Comment: @LutfullahHabibi I've added another example that should meet your request.